# Unable to route traffic to https listener from a nameserver in godaddy

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-route53

I have the following setup:

Some 10-15 domains bought at godaddy and 1 domain bought at aws route 53(.in domain).

In aws i have a load balancer(ELB) which uses the certificate of route 53 bought domain. The load balancer serves as the HTTPS endpoint and all my requests for my (.in) domain goes directly to my LB and its working fine as expected.

In godaddy, i have set a forwarding for all traffic for these 10-15 domains to my route53 record set of (.in) domain which inturn is connected to my ELB which listens on port 443 and port 80.

This works well for all HTTP requests but it doesn't work for HTTPS.

How do i make sure that when a user tries to access https://mydomainongodaddy.org it gets redirected to https://mydomainonawsrout53.in ?

Comment: Why don't you enable HTTPS only traffic in your ELB ?

Comment: @KushVyas, how would that solve my problem?